# Insert values from multiple arrays into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have the following arrays generated from a webform. I want to insert the data into a table I have with the columns 'surname' and 'ref'. I've not worked with arrays before - what's the most succinct way to iterate through the arrays?

For information, [0] represents the ID of the person in the database, [1] is their surname, and [2] is a boolean value. The query needs to update the table to set boolean value per [2] given the ID in [0]. (Surname is irrelevant for the query).

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => Jones
            [2] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => Anderson
            [2] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => Smith
            [2] => 0
        )

)
```

I've now tried to use a foreach loop to update the relevant fields but the problem I have is the start of the update query is repeated each time so the query fails:

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$item){
$invitee = $item[0];
$status = $item[2];
$query = "UPDATE invites SET reply_status='$status' WHERE id='$invitee'";
echo $query;
```

Where the resulting query generated is:

```
UPDATE invites SET reply_status='1' WHERE id='1'UPDATE invites SET reply_status='1' WHERE id='3'UPDATE invites SET reply_status='1' WHERE id='2'
```

Comment: Use a loop to generate an insert query. Not rocket surgery.

Comment: `For` or `foreach` loop will work.

Comment: @JohnConde I have tried to use foreach to get this to work but to no avail, I've edited question as above to show what I tried to do. Sure this is something very simple, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a "for each":

```
foreach($myarray as $key=>$item){
//create or execute your query using $item[0],$item[1],$item[2]
}
```

It will go through each key and allow you to acces the values through $item.

Comment: so, this is what I've done next:

foreach($_POST as $key=>$item){
//create or execute your query using $item[0],$item[1],$item[2]
$invitee = $item[0];
$status = $item[2];
$query = "UPDATE invites SET reply_status='$status' WHERE id='$invitee'";
echo $query;

This still doesn't work as it produces multiple UPDATE table SET value=x WHERE value=y so the query fails

Comment: You didn't properly format your code. It's not hard.
$query = " UPDATE `invites` SET `reply_status`='".$status."' WHERE `id`='".$invitee."' ";

Comment: The query produced (as displayed in my edited question above) is the same regardless of whether I use the original code or the formatted code you put in your comment. Surely the issue is that I can't have a list of UPDATE invites SET x=y, UPDATE invites SET x=y one after the other within the same query, and this is what I don't know how to fix. Thanks for your help much appreciated.

Comment: Dude are you serious ? Put ; between the queries. It's basic SQL. Or send the query to the database on each iteration.

Comment: Thanks, all sorted, it was my total lack of understanding of iterating through the array values with foreach rather than the SQL. All sorted anyway hence your answer marked as such. Thanks